# high chart X-axis values regardless series data

Tags: highcharts

I have following jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9v636zt3/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5]
    }]
});
});
```

Using highcharts, I want to show the x-axis labels 0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100 in series. but does not show it some how.

How can I force to show all the x-axis values?

Please help.

Comment: Thank you @RahulSharma. coudnt find the answer anywhere!!

Answer (score -2):

I think you are missing something i was able to plot your chat with the data you supply using this code below.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Average fruit consumption during one week'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100],
        plotBands: [{ 
            from: 4.5,
            to: 6.5,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
        }]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit units'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: ' units'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    },
    series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5,0,0,0]
}, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3]
}, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4]
}, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5]
}]
});
```

});

Comment: I wanted to show all the categories I have for x-axis and the code i have displays only 0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1

Comment: @yog2411, Ok, the reason why the other values on x-Axis is not showing is that there is no corresponding value for them on the series, on your x-Axis you have [0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100] and the corresponding data you are sending is  [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3], the solution is to pass an arbitrary value to it let's say 0, then you will have something like this [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3,0,0,0]  those values will show on x-Axis